# base url and scure url in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

By mistake i have done some silly mistake 
at admin i have changed secure url and base url in system/configure/web. but after that my website has damaged then i used db and changed in db table with original url(means first url) for restoring my website and delete all var/cache files.
But still problem is there.
when i open admin url ,its open fine 
but when open front url its taking as same what i changed

Please provide me some solution , May its would be simple but i tried all ways which i knew.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following queries:

```
update core_config_data value SET value = REPLACE(value, 'https', 'http') where path like '%base_url';
update core_config_data set value = '0' where path like 'web/secure_use_in%';
```

Afterwards, clear the /var/cache folder.

Comment: Thanks for reply But i did this still have same problem , admin url correctly working but at frontend url take as usual ... any suggestion .